# xampp vs lampp and how to tell the difference

Tags: xampp

If I open my GUI using the command "cd / opt/lampp" but the app is called xampp (I got it from the xampp website as instructed by my professor), is it lampp or xampp? How can I know the difference? People are saying xampp is a security hazard for some reason. Please excuse me if this is a duplicate question, I am very known to Ubuntu 16.04.2.  Also is their an instruction manual I can get somewhere, that has all the terminal commands and their respective definitions and uses?

Thanks so much in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your post and do not mix questions (xampp and a command line manual) in the same post. This site's format requires a single question per post. Thanks.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here, and suggest that if the app is called xampp and you got it from an xampp website, that the think you have installed is indeed, xampp

Answer (score 1):

From the [official website](https://www.apachefriends.org/):

> XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The XAMPP open source package has been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use.

As you can see, AMPP stands for Apache, MariaDB, PHP and Perl. It's a slight variation of the common LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) stack.

XAMPP is a suite of software that is available for Linux, Windows and macOS. The "X" is a generic placeholder for the platform.

The Linux version of XAMPP is also known as LAMPP. I think you can guess what WAMPP and MAMPP are, as well.